# How do I send a buffer in an HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, http

I have a file in memory (buffer) - there is no file on the file system.
I want to send that buffer to another server that talks HTTP.

For example, some API *A* creates a file in memory, [SignServer](https://www.signserver.org/doc/current/manual/integration.html#Web_Server_Interface) manipulates such files, and responds with a new buffer. My API takes the file from *A* and feeds it to SignServer.

I tried sending the file to SignServer in multiple ways, but it keeps responding with status 400 (missing field 'data' in request).

---

What I tried:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var data = querystring.stringify({
    workerName: 'PDFSigner',
    data: file_buffer
});

var request = new http.ClientRequest({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/signserver/process',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // I also tried 'multipart/form-data'
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
});

request.end(data);
```

I tried printing `data`, and it showed:

> workerName=PDFSigner&data=

Which is bad because `data` wasn't set to `file_buffer`.
I tried printing `file_buffer`, and it does have content (not null, not undefined, actually has bytes inside).
So stringifying the buffer gave an empty string.

I tried doing the same thing with the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module and it didn't work either.

Note that SignServer isn't written in Node nor JavaScript. It's a Java application, so it probably doesn't work with json (which is why I'm trying to do it with `querystring`). Yes, I tried sending json.

Comment: Please check this : https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback

Comment: @SauliusNext - Ok, so that's how I send binary data. But I need to send two things - one is a string, the other is binary, and I need to give them names so that the API can tell them apart.

Comment: Interesting read: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5827

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/form-data/form-data

Comment: Another interesting read: https://github.com/tj/node-querystring/issues/45

Comment: @robertklep Can I send binary data (buffer) not in a `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @IvanRubinson my guess is that the server you're trying to contact deals with file uploads? If so, it will be assuming `multipart/form-data`. Files typically aren't sent using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because it's not really suitable for large(ish) binary data.

Comment: @robertklep Here's a new question about how to do just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913650/how-to-send-a-buffer-in-form-data-to-signserver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `data` is set to an empty string is described in [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5827) and the solution is given in [this issue](https://github.com/tj/node-querystring/issues/45).

escape and stringify the buffer like so:

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
    workerName: 'PDFSigner',
    data: escape(file_buffer).toString('binary')
});
```

As @robertklep mentioned, your other problem is that you can't send a big file using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You'd need to do it with `multipart/form-data`.