# How to send a buffer in form-data to SignServer?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a file in memory (in a buffer), it doesn't exist on the file system (so I can't just stream that).

I'm trying to send it to [SignServer](https://www.signserver.org/doc/current/manual/integration.html#Web_Server_Interface) using HTTP.

Here's how I try to do it:

```
var formdata = require('form-data'); var form = new formdata();

form.append('workerName', 'PDFSigner');
form.append('data', file_buffer);
// or
// escape(file_buffer.toString('binary'))
// or
// file_buffer.toString('binary') (without escaping)

var request = form.submit('http://localhost:8080/signserver/process', function(err, res) {});
```

When I try appending `file_buffer` SignServer says that `data` is empty:

> Status 400 - Missing file content in upload

When I try appending `escape(file_buffer.toString('binary'))` (as suggested in [How do I send a buffer in an HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911060/how-do-i-send-a-buffer-in-an-http-request)) it's the same story.

When I try appending `file_buffer.toString('binary')` node.js crashes saying:

> node: ../src/stream_base.cc:157 int node::StreamBase::Writev(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo&): Assertion `(offset) <= (storage_size)' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

How do I correctly send the file (buffer) through HTTP (multipart/form-data) in Node.JS?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You explicitly need to set a `filename` for the `data` field, otherwise the buffer isn't uploaded as a file:

```
form.append('data', file_buffer, { filename : 'document.pdf' });
```

This is documented (albeit not very clearly) here: https://github.com/form-data/form-data#alternative-submission-methods (scroll down to the fourth example).

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append, I believe it should be `form.append('data', file_buffer, 'document.pdf');`

Comment: @Silvain actually, both solutions work :) I'm not sure if `form-data` used to require an object, or if it has always supported passing a filename string.

Comment: I was about to look into writing the buffer to a temp file and using fs to get a stream to that file, thanks!!!

Comment: I agree with @Silvain. Make sure the filename isn't in an object otherwise the file's name would look like this: name: object object

Comment: @PepperAddict don't confuse the module that we're talking about (`form-data`) with the web standard that @Silvain links to. The module gladly accepts an object as third argument (which is documented behaviour, as I pointed out in my answer).

Comment: @robertklep This is helpful even after 4 years, many thanks!

Comment: My saviour! Thanks!

Comment: `form.append('data', file_blob` need to convert the `Buffer` to `Blob` first

Comment: @Alireza it works fine if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated by Jun 2023**

According to [Mozila Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

> When the value is a Blob (or a File), you can specify its name with the filename parameter:

> ```
> formData.append("userpic", myFileInput.files[0], "chris.jpg");
> ```

If you change the filename `"chris.jpg"` to `{filename:"chris.jpg"}`, server (`nodejs` with `express-fileupload`) received `name: '[object Object]'` instead of the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you need to convert it from Buffer to Blob.

```js
const file_blob = new Blob([file_buffer], { type: file_type })

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file_blob, filename)
```