# Can't add filename option to form data in React Native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, native, form-data

I'm trying to send a file within a form data in React Native using an ArrayBuffer that represents the file.

```js
const FormData = require('form-data')
const form = new FormData()
form.append('file', file.data, { filename: file.name })
```

where `data` is the property with the array buffer.

When I send this form data, the API responds with `the param must be a file`, and I realized it is because the [third param in form data is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913650/how-to-send-a-buffer-in-form-data-to-signserver)

The above works fine for web app, but doesn't work for React Native.

Answer (score 0):

These code are worked on Android and iOS, it taken me for 4 days for find out the problem from FormData which has no attached filename. I hope to help you out

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        cropping: true,
        compressImageQuality: 0.5,
      }).then(image => {
        const {filename, mime, sourceURL, path, modificationDate} = image;

        formData.append('avatar', {
          uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? path : path.replace('file://', ''),
          type: mime,
          name:
            Platform.OS === 'android' ? `${modificationDate}.jpg` : filename,
        });

        dispatch(handleAvatarUpload(formData));
        setVisible(false);
      });
```