# Sending a file to the server WITHOUT using multer

Tags: node.js, axios, multer

I have a MERN stack app in which I'm sending text data and an image file to the server. I can see in the chrome network tab that all the fields are being sent in the payload, however, I am not receiving anything in the req.body or the req.file object.
Plase note that I am using redux-toolkit and axios to make the request, and on the backend I am NOT using multer.
**In the multer docs it says that multer adds a body and files or file object to the req object.** I need to know if I can send the data (text and file) to the server without using multer. Below is my code so far.

Setting up express:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

On the frontend the method sending/dispatching the data:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = new FormData();
    userData.append('name', name);
    userData.append('email', email);
    userData.append('password', password);
    userData.append('confirmPassword', confirmPassword);
    userData.append('userType', userType);
    userData.append('avatar', avatar);

    dispatch(registerUser(userData));
};
```

**My form does have the encType attribute set:**

```
<form encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={submitHandler}>
   //form fields
</form>
```

Sending the request using axios:

```
const registerUser = async (userData) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/register`, userData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } });
  return response;
};
```

**On the backend**

The route file:

```
router.post('/register', registerUser);
```

The controller file:

```
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); //{}
  console.log(req.files); //undefined
  console.log(req.file); //undefined
  res.send('OK');
});
```

**Chrome network tab after making the request:**
[image]

So, in a nutshell, I just need to recieve the data on the server. I wont the saving the image to disk so I dont think I need multer. I plan on reading the image file as a buffer and later save it to the database.

Comment: Ref Here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913650/how-to-send-a-buffer-in-form-data-to-signserverTn